# Why does Xcode show errors in the source code, but does my app compile and run properly?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, xcode8.2

It shows the error, but when I build or compile the app. It works perfectly. There is no error in runtime. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: What error does it show? Try cleaning the project.

Comment: does WrapperController inherit from UIViewController ?

Comment: @Sandu yes, the wrapperController inherits from UIViewController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These kinds of errors often occur if you have multiple targets (e.g. a "Test" target and an "App" target) and some files are linked with both targets and other files are linked with just the "App" target. So in order to fix this, browse through your files and make sure they are linked to the proper targets. Use the "target membership" pane to easily compare files in your project.

[image]